# Adding Carthage Support to an Existing Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, carthage

I've forked the [AEXML](https://github.com/kyledecot/AEXML) project and I'm trying add [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) support. I've added a framework target and a created a new Scheme that is marked as shared (see screenshots below). I am able to run `carthage build` and in my `Carthage/Build/iOS` I see:

[image]

When dragging the resulting `AEXML.framework` file into my example application the project will build however upon launching I receive:

[image]

I feel that I've messed up along the way somewhere but I'm not exactly sure how to go about fixing this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add run script at your example project's "Build Phase", like:

On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon and > choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script with the following contents:

```
 /usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

and then add the paths to the frameworks you would like to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:

```
 $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework
 $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
 $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/ReactiveCocoa.framework
```

Comment: You should add link reference to the quote.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to do this by myself by adding to the script to check if each framework was found in the BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR and then recursively copying them, if not. When that didn't work, I ended up with this linking issue:

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest
Referenced from: .../build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Specta.framework/Specta
Reason: image not found

I finally tried creating the copy files phase and included my frameworks and dSYMs, creating groups, then moved all these to the Frameworks group in Xcode 7.2. My linking issues were completely gone.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have points that framework binary was not found at runtime. Answer by [Abner Zhong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32966352/2777364) will work in most cases, but sometimes you have to try harder (for me it was unit tests target). To make it work [Carthage README](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/blob/master/README.md#adding-frameworks-to-unit-tests-or-a-framework) suggests:

> In rare cases, you may want to also copy each dependency into the build product (e.g., to embed dependencies within the outer framework, or make sure dependencies are present in a test bundle). To do this, create a new “Copy Files” build phase with the “Frameworks” destination, then add the framework reference there as well.

You can do this here:
[image: Xcode target settings]